# Flex swf file: how to inspect the method exposed?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

In every language there are a lot of tool to inspect the interface exposed by the compiled file, then what is the best tool for Flex swf file? I am debugging my code but the invoke always failed, I am writing my callee like below in my mcml file:

```
            public function playVideo():void
            {
                svid.play();
                return;
            }
```

And in another mcml I am using SWFLoader to load it and call it, but it always failed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean runtime introspection, or introspection while you're developing?

For runtime introspection, I've found [as3-reflect](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect) very helpful.

For developing, though… I just use FlexBuilder's autocompletion. I'd be interested to learn about a better way, though.

Comment: If the swf is dynamically loaded by SWFLoader, I think the auto completion can't work. Also I am interested how you can embed a SWF into another SWF without SWFLoader?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about tinkering with SWFs… I haven't had to do much of that =\